# FileNotFoundException solution?

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, filewriter, printwriter

Creating a program that will write the data from the array list to text file and I'm experiencing this `FileNotFoundException` even though the file exists. At the same time the computed data from my array is not written to it.

This is my code:

```
 public static void payrollReadFromFile(String filename) {

        // initializes br identifer as BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader br = null;

        payrolls.clear(); // removes all elements in arraylist employees

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("payroll.txt")); 
            try {

                 String name;               
                double   gincome, nincome, deduc, sss, pagibig, 
phil = 0; // initialize identifiers

                // reads each line through br identifier, and 
stores it on
                // temporary identifiers
                // loop continues until null is encountered
            while ((name = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    gincome = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                    sss = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                    pagibig = 
Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                    phil = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                    deduc = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                    nincome = 
Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());                    

                    // adds the data to payroll arraylist
                    payrolls.add(new Person( name, gincome, 
sss, pagibig, phil,deduc, nincome));
                }
            } finally {
                br.close(); // closes BufferedReader
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    // method which writes data into parameter 'filename'
    // uses PrintWriter and FileWriter
    public static boolean payrollWriteToFile(String filename) {
        boolean saved = false;
        PrintWriter pw = null; // pw is a PrintWriter identifier

        try {
            // instantiate pw as PrintWriter, FileWriter
            pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("payroll.txt")); 

            try {

                // for each loop. each data from payrolls is     
written to parameter

                for (Person payroll : payrolls) {

                    pw.println(payroll.getName());
                    pw.println(payroll.getGincome());
                    pw.println(payroll.getSss());
                    pw.println(payroll.getPagibig());
                    pw.println(payroll.getPhil());
                    pw.println(payroll.getDeduc());
                    pw.println(payroll.getNincome());


                }
                saved = true;
            } finally {
                pw.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return saved;
    }
```

Comment: Where in the filesystem is payroll.txt located?

Comment: @anakata it is in my workspace located at its project folder. even i did not specify the location of the txt file it will be written in that location am i right?

Comment: Could you please give us the stack trace--the jumble of code that prints out when an exception occurs? Also, path names are relative to the location of the `.class` file--figure out where that is and move your file accordingly.

Comment: @MathSquared11235 the error is ponting at this line

'    br = new BufferedReader(new     FileReader(filename)); '

Comment: Reading / writing files without specifying a path can be unpredictable unless you can make guarantees about where the program is actually running. Try `System.out.println(new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath());` to show the program's current directory. This will tell you where the program is running from, which is where it would expect to find the file.

Comment: @GargantuChet this error is solve now.. but can you help me in my other problem? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776630/cannot-write-in-the-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I took your code and modified it a little, this worked.  Make sure to use the parameter `filename` that is being passed to your method, right now you are hard-coding it in the method.

```
File file = new File(filename);
if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

Comment: so i should remove

    `br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("payroll.txt"));`

and replace it with that right?

Comment: Yes, the last line in my example should replace that.

Comment: Are you importing `java.io.File`? You really should use an IDE like Eclipse to solve these problems more easily.

Comment: and another thing sir it seemed that i cant write any data on my txt file , the data to be written is a computed value from my array list what do you think is the problem there?

Comment: thank you very much sir, i hope you'll help me in my other question

Comment: This is futile. All it does is change a FileNotFoundException into a pointless empty file that will immediately return EOF when read, and wastes disk space in the directory.

Comment: @EJP The OP asked a different question on how to write to a file properly. This one was just on how to solve the `FileNotFoundException`, which I did. I'm not going to program the OP's entire program for them.

Comment: @syb0rg It doesn't solve anything. It just changes one exception whose cause is rather obvious into a more obscure condition whose cause isn't obvious at all. It is a retrograde step. The idea is to fix the problem, not mask the symptoms.

Comment: @EJP I'm not seeing how I'm masking the symptoms with this solution.  The file is created, and I left the writing to it up to the OP.

Comment: @syb0rg Creating the file still leaves it empty. The OP will not be able to author the file until the program ends.

Comment: @MathSquared11235 Ya, I'm not sure you have a clue what you are talking about. I understand this will create an empty file.  The OP will definitely be able to write something to the file if he wishes before the program ends, and I left that job up to them to accomplish.

Comment: @syb0rg The OP is attempting to read from an existing file. It would be pointless to write to and read from the same file in the same program; that's what variables are for.

Comment: @MathSquared11235 Either you are mixing up your vocabulary, or you need to do some reading up on basic Java I/O. You're current logic is just nonsense.  I know what the OP is trying to do, and I solved the issue for them.

Answer (score 1):

Your file open statement:

```
   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("payroll.txt"));
```

is not using the variable filename that you passed into the method.

You need:

```
   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
```

You may also want to use the File object instead.

Comment: The `String` that is passed to the function might still point to the wrong location of the file. Using the parameter value in place of what the OP is using now I doubt will fix anything.

Comment: It's not wrong. It is an obvious error in the OP's code and it may indeed answer the question. If it doesn't it's because the OP is wrong and the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @EJP You are wrong. Try making the OP's code work with this solution (which I tried, and it failed), and then tell me it's not wrong.

Comment: @syb0rg  A method shouldn't use a constant when there is a parameter clearly provided for the same purpose. That is clearly a bug in the method. It is pointless for anyone to try to make the OP's code work unless he has the file in the correct place, and it isn't even clear that the OP has that.

Comment: @EJP I understand that he should be using a parameter in place of the constant. I originally had a comment asking the OP why he wasn't making use of the parameter, but I deleted it. I'm just saying that this is not the cause of the issue.  If you pass `payroll.txt` to that function, it still does not work.

Comment: @syb0rg You're not in a position to say whether it works or not unless you're using the same computer system as the OP, and you aren't.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make sure the file is in the right location. Paths are relative to the location of the `.class` file. For example, "`payroll.txt`" refers to "`C:\path\to\class\file\payroll.txt`".

Also, do reconfigure the `BufferedReader` to use the `filename` parameter, as others have pointed out.

Do not just create a file in the program; this is just masking the problem, which is a file stored in the wrong place. You could use this for testing to find where the file should go, but then remove that line and just place the file you need to use there.